I want to display the data I got from the fake api with the curl method
I want to display the information I received from the fake api using the curl method using foreach, and I get the following error:

Trying to access array offset on value of type int

<?php
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl , array(
        CURLOPT_URL =>  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums",
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET'
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $values = json_decode($response, true);
    foreach ((array)$values as $value){
        echo $value['userId']."</br>";
        echo $value["id"]."</br>";
        echo $value["title"]."</br>";
    }
?>


What's your question about this code? Did you check what $values contains? Is this problem really related to cURL itself?

curl_exec can return false on failure, you should be checking for that, and if it happens, check the more specific error with die(curl_error($curl));

Further, when decoding JSON I'd encourage you to always use the JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR flag so that you aren't hiding any possible errors: https://3v4l.org/QU4O9

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php: "Returns true on success or false on failure. However, if the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option is set, it will return the result on success, false on failure." - you did not do the bold part, so you will only be getting true or false. And the result of json_decode(true) is simply int(1).
